# Auto Increment with letter and numbers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible in Excel to auto increment numbers with a letter at the front? In this case every 9 rows up the number by 10.

```
H-2301-0901-501-000-350
H-2301-0901-501-000-350
H-2301-0901-501-000-350
H-2301-0901-501-000-350
H-2301-0901-501-000-350
H-2301-0901-501-000-350
H-2301-0901-501-000-350
H-2301-0901-501-000-350
H-2301-0901-501-000-350
H-2301-0901-501-000-360
H-2301-0901-501-000-360
H-2301-0901-501-000-360
H-2301-0901-501-000-360
H-2301-0901-501-000-360
H-2301-0901-501-000-360
H-2301-0901-501-000-360
H-2301-0901-501-000-360
H-2301-0901-501-000-360
```

Comment: And what is supposed to happen at 990 at the end?

Comment: it changes -501-000-990 it will go to 502-000-010 etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula:

```
="H-2301-0901-501-000-" & INT((ROW()-1)/9)*10+10
```

to start from 10

or formula:

```
="H-2301-0901-501-000-" & INT((ROW()+305)/9)*10+10
```

to start from 350

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. saved me hours of work.